# How to open fotorama fullscreen by click on any image?

Tags: fotorama

5 images displayed and need to open fullscreen fotorama slider with these images:

```
<div class="img-list">

    <a href="????"><img src="img1"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img2"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img3"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img4"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img5"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the [Artem Polikarpov's jQuery gallery](http://fotorama.io/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call fotorama gallery in full screen mode via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014907/call-fotorama-gallery-in-full-screen-mode-via-api/19064471).

Answer (score 1):

Set data-allowfullscreen to true. Like this.

```
<div class="img-list" data-allowfullscreen="true">
    <a href="????"><img src="img1"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img2"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img3"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img4"></a>
    <a href="????"><img src="img5"></a>
</div>
```