# How to open fotorama fullscreen mode by click on main image?

Tags: image, click, fullscreen, fotorama

I'm using fotorama js plugin for product gallery. 
How to turn on fullscreen mode when clicking on main image (not thumbnails)? 
I want to allow user to open fullscreen mode by click on image instead fullscreen icon on right top corner.

This answer is not working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19064471/4680550

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of looking for solution I finally found it. Just make fullscreen icon transparent, full height and full width to cover main image:

```
.fotorama__fullscreen-icon {
    background: url('../img/bg.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

Comment: Problem with video

Answer (score -2):

look on sippet below or look on this example on http://jsfiddle.net/slovnet/gk9998ct/

```js
var $fotoramaDiv = jQuery('.fotorama_custom').fotorama({
  click:false,
  allowfullscreen:true,
});

    // 2. Get the API object.
    var fotorama = $fotoramaDiv.data('fotorama');

// if you want add handler on one left click
jQuery('.fotorama').click(function(){
    fotorama.requestFullScreen();    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>
<!-- Fotorama -->
<div class="fotorama_custom" data-width="700" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/sports">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/animals">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/city">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/people">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200/transport">
</div>
```